# Record buffers smaller than AudioRecord's minBufferSize

Tags: java, android, audio

In my current project of a local VoIP app, I have to stream audio from one device and play it as fast as possible on another device connected to the same network using UDP. So I made a very basic demo android app using `AudioRecord` and `DatagramSocket` and a very simple C++ program to play the received audio using a fairly small circular buffer.

An important point is that the minimum delay seems to be decided by `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize()` which resulted in my configuration *(48kHz 16 channels mono PCM on a real Android phone)* to be 3840 bytes = 1920 samples = **40ms** of audio.

```java
while (isRecording == true) {
    // read the actual amount of bytes inside the buffer
    int read = mAudioRecord.read(audioBuffer, 0, minBufferSize);

    // prepare the UDP packet
    packet = new DatagramPacket(audioBuffer, read, address, port);

    // send the packet
    mDatagramSocket.send(packet);
}
```

I managed to achieve near real-time audio *(under 50ms latency)*, but after a couple of testing, I came to the conclusion that playing the `AudioRecord`'s buffers as fast as possible is not an optimal solution as it results in gaps in the audio *(**underflows**)* as well as clicks and audio being cut *(**overflows/overwrite** of audio)*, and after some investigation the culprit was simply the unstable ping between the two devices, and even a small lag could result in a terrible audio distorsion as shown below:

[image: Illustration of UDP audio packets being sent and lag consequences on them]

And the only solution I found is to manually delay the playback of EVERY packet by 10ms, solving the problem in the precedent scenario but increasing the overall latency to 40 + 10 = **50ms**, and if I need to keep good audio with up to 20ms ping spikes, I would have to increase the latency to **60 ms** and so on, resulting in a delayed audio that will be even mode delayed if redirected and sent online which is not really acceptable for VoIP *(trying to keep it below the 150ms bar)*.

So I thought the perfect solution would be to reduce the amount of time it takes to record a single packet so I could add on top of it the wanted latency (e.g. if each audio buffer had only 20ms of audio I could add up to 30ms of delay to each playback and still keep it only 50ms delayed which is pretty good for VoIP).

But I'm not sure if this is possible, I wonder if there is a tricky way of achieving that. I noticed that `AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize()` on the Android Studio Emulator *(on Windows 10)* gives 640 bytes **(~7 ms)** with the same PCM configuration which is an amazing number, but on the Genymotion emulator *(on Debian)* the minimum buffer size is 4480 bytes **(~47 ms)**.

Comment: Why do you think that a latency of 60ms is not acceptable for VoIP? The [recommendation by the International Telecommunication Union](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-suznjevic-tsvwg-delay-limits-00.xml#rfc.section.4.1) seems to be "it should be lower than 150ms, but delay between 150ms and 400ms are still acceptable"

Comment: @ThomasKläger since it's local VoIP I'm trying to reduce the latency as much as technically possible, to be able later on to redirect that very same audio in an online VoIP app in the receiving machine that would add more delay. That's why I want it to be as low as possible so that the total latency wouldn't be greater than 150ms.

Comment: See my answer below for a way to solve the part of your problem on the android side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to read smaller amounts of data from the `AudioRecord` and send them as soon as possible to the server.

The [`AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord#getMinBufferSize(int,%20int,%20int)) JavaDoc states:

> Returns the minimum buffer size required for the successful creation of an AudioRecord object, in byte units. Note that this size doesn't guarantee a smooth recording under load, and higher values should be chosen according to the expected frequency at which the AudioRecord instance will be polled for new data.

So this is the minimum size for the buffer that `AudioRecord` should allocate. Depending on how often you can fetch data from the `AudioRecord` instance it might even be required to specify a bigger buffer.

The [`AudioRecord`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord) JavaDoc in turn states (emphasis added):

> Upon creation, an AudioRecord object initializes its associated audio buffer that it will fill with the new audio data. The size of this buffer, specified during the construction, determines how long an AudioRecord can record before "over-running" data that has not been read yet. **Data should be read from the audio hardware in chunks of sizes inferior to the total recording buffer size.**

So the documentation explicitly tells you **not** to try to read the whole buffer at once!

---

You can for example setup the `AudioRecord` object as

```
mAudioRecord = new AudioRecord(
    MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
    48000, // sampeRate
    AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
    AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
    9600 // buffer size: 100ms
);
```

and the polling code can read 480 samples every 10ms and send them to the server:

```
final int BUFFER_SIZE = 960; // 1 package every 10ms
byte[] audioBuffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
while (isRecording) {
    // read the actual amount of bytes inside the buffer
    int read = mAudioRecord.read(audioBuffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    // prepare the UDP packet
    packet = new DatagramPacket(audioBuffer, read, address, port);

    // send the packet
    mDatagramSocket.send(packet);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it's working a lot better than having to wait 40ms between each read! Interestingly enough however, it seems now to be waiting for 20ms per read then 0, then 20ms again then 0, and so on. I wonder why it isn't stable anymore, any idea?